# How to use echo output as a variable

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I simulated the situation where the value of variable `bar` is `$foo`. `foo` is a variable too, which has the value `hello`.

```
$ foo=hello
$ bar=$(echo "\$foo")
$ echo $bar
$foo
```

How I can get to `hello`, **given** `foo="hello"` and `bar="$foo"`?

I tried:

```
$ echo $(echo $bar)
```

But the output still is:

```
$foo
```

Comment: Change the second line to `bar=$(echo "$foo")`; the $ character should not be excaped.

Comment: I think the original poster wanted to echo  the current value of `$foo` in case it is updated after the `bar=...` assignment.

Comment: [Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)' just use 'cmd foo'](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval` like this:

```
$ foo=hello
$ bar=$(echo "\$foo")
$ echo "$bar"
$foo
$ eval echo "$bar"
hello
$ foo=world
$ eval echo "$bar"
world
```

In the above example, the `eval` bash builtin command will parse the arguments once more, so that the `$bar` variable contents will be interpreted once more as a variable (`$foo`) and its ***current contents*** (`hello` in the first case and `world` in the second case) will be used as the argument to the `echo` command.

Answer (score 4):

use a "nameref"

```bsh
declare -n bar=foo

foo=hello
echo "$bar"    # => hello

foo=world
echo "$bar"    # => world
```

Or an indirect variable

```bsh
unset bar
bar=foo

foo=hello
echo "${!bar}"    # => hello

foo=world
echo "${!bar}"    # => world
```